# How to fetch list of files from path

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list

I have a code which is used to fetch the list of files from path.I am trying to fetch list of files named Items from Path named FileNamepath.I have used for-loop where i get individual files.I need to combine all those Individual files and put it in a string[] FileNames(files should be in a list).Can anyone please suggest me the correct way of doing it.

Thanks

```
if (Directory.Exists(FileNamePath))
{
    //con.Open(); 
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    string qry="select FileName from MembersFiles where fk_MemberId='" + GlobalValues.Member_PkId + "' and Document_Type='" + doc + "'";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        // con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (objReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (objReader.Read())
                {                       
                    string item = objReader.GetString(objReader.GetOrdinal("FileName"));
                    items.Add(item);  // List Of Files                      
                }
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();

    string[] fileNames1;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        fileNames1 = Directory.GetFiles(FileNamePath, items[i]); // Fetching individual files
    }
  //  String[] fileNames=   // here i need to put all files(list of files)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Linq refactor:

```
        if (Directory.Exists(FileNamePath))
        {
            List<string> dbFileNames = null;
            string qry = "select FileName from MembersFiles where fk_MemberId='" + GlobalValues.Member_PkId + "' and Document_Type='" + doc + "'";
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dbFileName = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                    .Select(r => r[0].ToString()).ToList();
                con.Close();
            }
            string[] fileNames1 = dbFileNames.Select(f =>
            Path.Combine(FileNamePath, f)).ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply.but it is not fetching any files and count=0

Comment: can you show the **sample data** in the `FileName` column? I'm following your logic and in theory your code could not fetch any file either.

Comment: FileName consists of a Image file like LoanForm_Penguins.jpg

Comment: Thanks a lot Lei Yang..after doing few modifications along with your code its working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
            ProcessFile(fileName);
```

check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.GetFiles()` method will give you the list of file_path, and you want to get the file names only so you have to do something like the following:

```
var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(path)
                                 .Select(x=>Path.GetFileName(x));
```

You can also try `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` if you need to get the file name without extension.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.but my requirement is to fetch only those files which are present in a list named "items" from filenamepath.